# Replace all characters after the first number block

Tags: c#, regex, serial-port

I have an array with strings like COM1, COM22, COM3abc, COM4!"§", COM5656! and so on. Now a want to replace all characters after the first block of numbers occurred so that I get: COM1, COM22, COM3, COM4, COM5656. I'm not so familiar with regex but I tried a lot of different regex like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < comPorts.Length; i++)
    comPorts[i] = Regex.Replace(comPorts[i], @"\D*(\d+)\D*", "$1");
```

But this regex also removes the COM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
Regex.Replace(comPorts[i], @"(\d+).*", "$1")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pggz0w/1)

The `(\d+).*` regex will match and capture the first (leftmost) one or more digit text chunk and then `.*` will grab the rest of the string, and `$1` will replace the whole match with the digits captured. Note you need to pass `RegexOptions.Singleline` as the last argument to `Regex.Replace` if the string can have more than one line.